# HTML5 Select photos directly from Photo Library on Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

Is there any way to directly open the **Photo Library** and select photos when clicking on HTML file control on Safari iOS/WebViewController?

I was able to directly open camera and documents (only on iOS 14 devices) from the file control using the following codes.

To open the camera:

```html
<input type="file" name="media_file" accept="image/*, video/*" capture="environment">
```

And to open the documents:

```html
<input type="file" name="media_file" accept="application/pdf" >
```

But couldn't open the Photo Library. Instead it is showing the following menu and from there I have to open the Photo Library to chose photos. But I need to open the Photo Library directly without showing the menu. Is it possible?

[image: iOS file menu]